# Make collectionView scrolls as AppStore games section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, app-store

I have a collectionView with horizontal scroll direction and paging enabled, now I want to make it scroll as smoothly as the games section on the AppStore.

To be more specific this is how I want the first cell to be:

**EDIT**

> I actually achieved both of the next images one with the smaller width
>   of the cell and the next with the .centeredHorizontally in selectItem,
>   my problem is the non smoothly scrolling.

[image]

As you can see a little of the second cell is appearing.

And here is the next cells:

[image]

As you can see now the previous and the next cell are appearing.

I managed to do this by setting this part of code but with bouncing no smoothly as AppStore.

This is the code I used:

```
       func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            var visibleRect = CGRect()

            visibleRect.origin = collectionView.contentOffset
            visibleRect.size = collectionView.bounds.size

            let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)

            let visibleIndexPath: IndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) ?? IndexPath()
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: visibleIndexPath[1], section: 0)
            collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally )

        }
```

And this is my collectionView code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let frameSize = collectionView.frame.size
        return CGSize(width: frameSize.width - 30, height: frameSize.height - 40)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
    }
```

Comment: To see a little of the second cell is appearing, Set the size of cell is little smaller than the collection view width.

Comment: @pkc456 sorry I forgot to mention it, I already achieve this by make the width of cell a little smaller than the collectionView

Comment: my problem is when I scroll that is going left and right before it's stabilize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Example project here](https://github.com/danya0365/appstore-collectionview-swift)

In class property

```
     var itemSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
     @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
     @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
     fileprivate let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

In viewDidLoad or awakeFormNib(If in collectionViewCell or tableViewCell)

```
    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    }
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 8)
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false
    layoutIfNeeded()

    let width = collectionView.bounds.size.width-24
    let height = width * (3/4)
    itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    layoutIfNeeded()
```

Implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        return sectionInsets
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return itemSize
    }
```

Implement ScrollViewDelegate

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let pageWidth = itemSize.width
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
    var factor: CGFloat = 0.5
    if velocity.x < 0 {
        factor = -factor
        print("right")
    } else {
        print("left")
    }

    let a:CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x/pageWidth
    var index = Int( round(a+factor) )
    if index < 0 {
        index = 0
    }
    if index > collectionViewDataList.count-1 {
        index = collectionViewDataList.count-1
    }
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
    collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}
```

See example screenshot from my project at Past rides section
I have implemented uicollectionview in collectionViewCell

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check it

Comment: I checked it and I have one problem as I have with the one I made...
When I scroll if I tap on the cell (before the scrolling stops) the scrolling stops.

Comment: I will try to fixed that situation.

Comment: simply add `collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: false)` in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set `collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true` and remove your `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method

Comment: I did that but every cell after the first isn't horizontally centered

Comment: Did you set the scroll direction of your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to `horizontal`?